# change variable only for one ng-repeat document angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to show more text when an user clicks a `read more` button:

```
<md-content class="md-padding" layout-xs="column" layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <div flex-xs flex-gt-xs="50" layout="column" ng-repeat="paquete in paquetes">
    <md-card>
      <md-card-title layout="row" layout-xs="column">
        <md-card-title-media layout-margin>
          <img ng-src="{{paquete.img}}" class="md-card-image margin-auto" alt="image caption">
        </md-card-title-media>
        <md-card-title-text>
          <span class="md-headline blue">{{paquete.title}}</span>
          <span class="md-subhead dark-blue">{{paquete.desc | limitTo: limit.limit}}
             <span class="threedots" ng-show="mas.mas">... </span>
             <span style="cursor: pointer;" class="blue underlined" 
                ng-click="limitFunction(paquete.desc)">Leer 
                   <span class="mas" ng-show="mas.mas">más</span>
                   <span class="menos" ng-show="menos.menos">menos</span>.
             </span>
          </span>
        </md-card-title-text>
      </md-card-title>
    </md-card>
  </div>    
</md-content>
```

I'm limiting the initial descripction `{{paquete.desc | limitTo: limit.limit}}` and letting the user click to read more `ng-click="limitFunction(paquete.desc)"`

My controller:

```
$scope.limit = {limit: 200};

$scope.limitFunction = function (desc) {
    $scope.limit.limit = desc.length;
};
```

But when I click on one of the ng-repeat elements, the `$scope.limit` changes to all of them instead of the one I'm clicking.

How do I change the `$scope.limit` to only the one that I'm clicking?

Comment: You set the limit globally but you should set it on your repeated item or track if somehow for eahc item, like `paquete.limit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the limit on the paquete object and pass that into your limit function

```
 <span class="md-subhead dark-blue">{{paquete.desc | limitTo: paquete.limit}}<span class="threedots" ng-show="mas.mas">... </span><span style="cursor: pointer;" class="blue underlined" ng-click="limitFunction(paquete)">Leer <span class="mas" ng-show="mas.mas">más</span><span class="menos" ng-show="menos.menos">menos</span>.</span></span>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.limitFunction = function (paquete) {
    paquete.limit = paquete.desc.length;
};
```